# PHP var in jquery call

Tags: php, jquery

This is working, but there is probably a better way to pass the php var. does anyone have any options? thanks

```
<?php $slide = "fade"; ?>

$(document).ready(function()
{   

    $("#showcase_right").awShowcase({transition : "<?php echo $slide; ?>"});
});
```

Comment: All I can think of is `<?= $slide; ?>`

Comment: this is the only way, but if you need search by dynamic value you mmay need use ajax

Comment: In the general case it would be better to write `{transition : <?php echo json_encode($slide); ?>}` (no double quotes around PHP), but your way is OK if the string does not contain quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way would be using `json_encode` to convert the PHP string to JavaScript. In this case it makes no real difference but when you have other strings it ensures that you'll always have valid JavaScript no matter what the PHP variable contains.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#showcase_right").awShowcase({
        transition : <?php echo json_encode($slide); ?>
    });
});
```

Another option would be storing the value e.g. in a `data-` attribute, e.g. in the `<body>` tag:

```
<body data-transition="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($slide); ?>">
```

Then you can access it in your JavaScript code using `$('body').data('transition')`

Comment: Why would you `json_encode` a string literal?

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Thanks, json_encode it is

Comment: Because that will ensure that he gets a valid JS string. As I said, doesn't matter with a simple string like the one he has. But if it could contain characters such as linebreaks, quotes, etc. it's the safest way to deal with them.

Comment: A bit over-analytical if you ask me for this case. A transition value would need to have a non-spaced, single line string anyway so json_encode wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're doing it right. Relax :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing isn't really defining a variable. You're defining a constant in variable form.

If the transition value can be changed by the user, you can keep it all on the client.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#showcase_right").awShowcase({transition : strSlide || 'fade'});
});
```

Where `strSlide` would be the "variable".

Answer (score 0):

You could plug the PHP variable into a hidden input field, then grab that input into a javascript variable. I think your way is better though, that was merely speculating on other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like your current method, you could do something like this (change the implementation to your liking):

```
var config = {
    "slide":"<?php echo "fade"; ?>" // or have a variable here
}

$(document).ready(function()
{   

    $("#showcase_right").awShowcase({transition : config['slide']});
});
```

That way you decouple your PHP from javascript as much as possible. Allowing you to change the config with relative ease.